# How can I tell if the argument passed to my function is a list of numbers, or a list of lists of numbers?

Tags: ruby

I have these methods:

```
def get_width(arg)
    return arg[0]
end

def get_height(arg)
    return arg[1]
end
```

`arg` will either be of the form `[200, 400]` or of the form `[[200, 400], [300, 600], [150,780], ...]`  If it is the former, my functions work.  But if it is the latter, I just want to use the first entry.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_width(arg)
    arg = arg[0] if arg[0].is_a? Array
    return arg[0]
end

def get_height(arg)
    arg = arg[0] if arg[0].is_a? Array
    return arg[1]
end
```

Comment: No need to replicate the unnecessary `return` :)

Comment: `arg[0].is_a?( Array ) ? arg[0][0] : arg[0]`

Comment: The return is necessary to make explicit exactly what is being returned.  Eliminating it would replicate unnecessary thinking.

Comment: @JonCrowell - actually, idiomatic ruby does not require the `return` statement, and proficient rubyists habitually skip it. I've kept the code as similar as possible to yours just to highlight the actual solution, rather than refactor the OP code

Comment: Yes, I know the return statement is not required and proficient rubyists habitually skip it -- I consider this to be a good example of false efficiency.

Comment: @JonCrowell this is a bit off-topic, and I would argue that this is not at all about efficiency (more about readability), and I understand where you are coming from (probably Java :-P). I do think though that it is beneficiary to go with the adage "when in Rome - do as Romanians do" - as a ruby programmer - you're not only writing ruby, you also need to _read_ ruby written by others, and getting used to using the `return` statement only where needed (and indenting your code with 2 spaces instead of 4) will also make reading other ppl's code easier. Coding is not just syntax, it`s also dialect.

Comment: @UriAgassi Actually, I'm coming from Python.  I wasn't speaking about efficiency in terms of processing time, I was speaking about efficiency in terms of time I spend reading and trying to understand the code.  I'm not sure why you suggest that leaving off the return statement is more readable, since it is less explicit.  It is always the case that clarity and readability are the same thing.  If you think it is more readable just because it is shorter and it takes less time to read fewer words, then I think you are mistaken - compressed and obfuscated code is more readable by that definition.

Comment: @JonCrowell - I'm not saying it is more readable because it is shorter, I'm saying it is more readable because it is _ruby_... it is like initializing variables with 'null' in Java, or asking for the "lift" when you are looking for an elevator in America - it looks awkward and out of context, and hence breaks the reading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use function to get the type.

```
def get_width(arg)
  if arg[0].is_a? Array
    return arg[0][0]
  else
    return arg[0]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
def width_and_height(arr)
    [*arr.first].first, [*arr.last].first
end  

a = [200, 400]
b = [[200, 400], [300, 600]] 

width_and_height(a) #=> [200, 400]
width_and_height(b) #=> [200, 300]
```

Note:

```
[*[200, 400].first].first
  #=> [*200].first
  #=> [200].first
  #=> 200

[*[[200, 400], [300, 600]].first].first
  #=> [*[200, 400]].first
  #=> [200, 400].first
  #=> 200
```